# Python list to csv throws error: iterable expected, not numpy.int64

Tags: python, csv

I want to write a list into a csv,When trying to do it I receive the below error

```
out.writerows(fin_city_ids)
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not numpy.int64
```

My code is as below

```
org_id.append([pol_id,bldest_id])
fin_ids=list(org_city_id['org_id'].unique())
print(fin_ids)

out = csv.writer(open("D:/dataset/fin_ids.csv","w"), delimiter='|')
out.writerows(fin_ids)
```

Below is the output from fin_ids

```
[1002774, 0, 1000702, 1000339, 1001620, 1000710, 1000202, 1003143, 147897, 31018, 1001502, 1002812, 1003026, 1003280, 1003289, 1002714, 133191, 5252218, 6007821, 1002632]
```

Org_id is a dataFrame which contains duplicate ids .fin_ids is a list which contains unqiue values of ids .Fin ID is a list of unique ids derived from the data frame org_id.

output desired is a CSV with all the values in separate rows as I am going to load the data into a sql table later .

Comment: What do you see when you print out `fin_ids`. Please add that here and show us what's contained `org_id` as well. `csv` is complaining because you're not providing it with a sequence for `writerows`.

Comment: Try `outfile = open("D:/dataset/fin_ids.csv","w"); out = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='|'); out.writerow(fin_ids); outfile.close()`. Use `writerow` for one list or array.

Comment: well this just creates a kind of single row

Comment: What's your desired output then?

Comment: updated the question with output details

Comment: `outfile = open("D:/dataset/fin_ids.csv","w"); out = csv.writer(outfile); out.writerows(map(lambda x: [x], fin_ids)); outfile.close()`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get this done in many ways. But if you wish to `writerows` from the `csv` module, then you will have to turn your list `fin_ids` into a sequence of lists first:

```
fin_ids = [1002774, 0, 1000702, 1000339, 
   1001620, 1000710, 1000202, 1003143, 147897, 
   31018, 1001502, 1002812, 1003026, 1003280, 
   1003289, 1002714, 133191, 5252218, 6007821, 1002632]

outfile = open('D:/dataset/fin_ids.csv','w')
out = csv.writer(outfile)
out.writerows(map(lambda x: [x], fin_ids))
outfile.close()
```

Another way would be to just use the `.to_csv()` method from pandas `Series`. Since you started with a dataframe, you could just do:

```
org_city_id['org_id'].unique().to_csv("D:/dataset/fin_ids.csv", index=False)
```

Both of these should generate a csv file with the following data:

```
1002774
0
1000702
1000339
1001620
1000710
1000202
1003143
147897
31018
1001502
1002812
1003026
1003280
1003289
1002714
133191
5252218
6007821
1002632
```