# How to fix "Error: iterable expected, not int" when writing to a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

Why is my CSV write function not working? This seems to be a very simple code but the CSV `writerow` is asking for an iterable. I just need to write the 1,2,3 in a column.

```
import csv

data = [1,2,3]

output = 'output.csv'

with open(output,'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for item in data:
        writer.writerow(item)
```

Comment: Have you seen this question? I think that writerow expects a list. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39282731/92953

Comment: A row must be an iterable of strings or numbers for Writer objects and a dictionary mapping fieldnames to strings or numbers (by passing them through str() first) for DictWriter objects.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: try changing to, ``writer.writerow([item])``

Comment: Not to be overly picky, but if there is literally only one value on each line, why is CSV getting involved? For consistent newline format? Because you didn't pass `newline=''` to `open`, so you won't be getting that anyway.

Comment: What can I use if not CSV? Are you implying I use txt instead?

Comment: Yes, for this output, you should be using simple text.  You use none of the added complexity of a CSV for this task.  Also, please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We expect you to do your basic research before posting here.  This includes reading the documentation for `writerow` and checking the on-line examples.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an integer but a list is expected.

```
import csv

data = [[1],[2],[3]]

output = 'output.csv'

with open(output,'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for item in data:
        writer.writerow(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

We need to provide a list to the CSV writer `writerow` function, in which there are values for 1 complete row.

e.g

```
import csv

data = [1,2,3]

output = 'output.csv'

with open(output,'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(data) # as data includes only 1 row. For multiple rows write every row with a loop
```