# Writing data to a text file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write `mean,var,std`  to a `.txt` file but I am getting an error.

```
import csv
mean = 50.00001075309713
var = 4.120598729047652
std = 2.0299257939756448

with open('Radius.txt', 'w+') as f: 
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    print("Mean =",mean)
    print("var =",var)
    print("std =",std)
    writer.writerow(mean)
    writer.writerow(var)
    writer.writerow(std)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    writer.writerow(mean)

Error: iterable expected, not float
```

The expected output is

```
mean = 50.00001075309713
var = 4.120598729047652
std = 2.0299257939756448
```

Comment: We can see from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) that: *"A row must be an iterable of strings or numbers"*.  A `float` is not iterable, so you need to wrap it in an iterable container like a `list` or a `tuple`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Error: iterable expected, not int" when writing to a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668716/how-to-fix-error-iterable-expected-not-int-when-writing-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: Do you need the csv format or are you happy with a txt file containing the 3 lines from your expected output?

Comment: CSV format is not mandatory. The expected output in a txt file will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
writer.writerow(mean)
writer.writerow(var)
writer.writerow(std)
```

to:

```
writer.writerow((mean, var, std))
```

The requirement for an iterable means whatever you pass to writerow must be something which can be looped through.  The fix here is to put your values into a tuple, the inner bracketed values.  It works because tuples can be looped through.

To write the values as a single line with variable prefixes (OP's comment) use:

```
writer.writerow((f'{mean = }  {var = }  {std = }', ))
```

Comment: I have now included the expected output. How can ```writer.writerow((mean, var, std))``` be modified?

Comment: Modify any of the values mean, var and std by assigning their values: var = 123...  Each new call to writerow would create a new tuple from the modified values.  A tuple itself cannot be modified, but that doesn't affect our use case here because we are creating a new tuple purely for writerow.  The tuple doesn't exist after that but your values still do in their respective named variables mean, var and std.

Comment: I mean how do I save values in this format: ```mean = 50.00001075309713
var = 4.120598729047652
std = 2.0299257939756448``` as shown in the expected output.

Comment: see updated reply

Comment: With the updated reply, it is saving as ```m,e,a,n, ,=, ,5,0,.,0,0,0,0,1,0,7,5,3,0,9,7,1,3, ,v,a,r, ,=, ,4,.,1,2,0,5,9,8,7,2,9,0,4,7,6,5,2, ,s,t,d, ,=, ,2,.,0,2,9,9,2,5,7,9,3,9,7,5,6,4,4,8``` which is not the expected output.

Comment: apologies, punctuation fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the clarification from the comments a way without using csv but just a txt file:

```
mean = 50.00001075309713
var = 4.120598729047652
std = 2.0299257939756448

with open('Radius.txt', 'w+') as f: 
    f.write(f"mean = {str(mean)}\n")
    f.write(f"var = {str(var)}\n")
    f.write(f"std = {str(std)}\n")
```